# Smallest natural number relatively prime to $\{2,...,n\}$

Tags: number-theory

Let $X$ be the smallest natural number that is relatively-prime w.r.t. all of $\{2,...,n\}$. How can $X$ be expressed as an asymptotic function of $n$?

Thanks,
Daniel.

Comment: @TonyK maybe they want an upper bound on that prime? In that case $1 + \prod_{i=2}^n i$ works.

Comment: TonyK - yes, you are right, my question was rather silly, I'm afraid. I guess this follows from Bertrand's theorem?

Comment: $X$ is just the smallest prime that is $> n$. I don't know what you mean exactly by an "asymptotic function of $n$", but perhaps $f(X)=n$ satisfies your needs?

Comment: Forgive me for screwing up the temporal order of the comments! Daniel, $f(X)=n$ doesn't follow from Bertrand's postulate $-$ that only gives $X<2n$. But the Prime Number Theorem guarantees that $X/n$ tends to $1$.

Comment: Why not $X=1$ ?

Comment: Hi TonyK, I guess my question was not as clear as it should have been (but nevertheless you answered it already).  By asking what is X asymptotically as a function of n, I meant to ask what is the function f such that X=\Theta(f(n)). This "big Theta" notation (see link below) disregards constant multiplicative/additive factors so, as you responded previously, f(X)=n does answer my question.  The response by Lwins  gives a more exact bound but f(n)=n still holds. 

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_computational_complexity

Comment: That's a better link for understanding the big Theta notation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @TonyK, $X$ is just the smallest prime that greater than $n$. For an upper bound you can take $X \leq n+O(n^{0.525})$ by [a result from Baker, Harman and Pintz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap) . By the celebrated result from Zhang (i.e., prime gaps take finite value infinitely often), the lower bound *cannot* be better than $X \geq n+c$ for some constant $c$. If you believe that the twin prime conjecture is true you can just take $c=2$.